# How can I make a paragraph after a float element to not float?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I don't want the third paragraph to float like two others. What should I do that my further paragraphs don't float like the first two?

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}

p.username {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="My picture" width="default" height="default">
<p class="username">@BilalKhan615</p>
<p>Getting started with HTML and CSS!</p>
<!-- This is the paragraph which I do not want to float like the other two -->
<p> Hello Everyone!</p>
```

Comment: See [ask] for tips on how to make your question simpler and easier to debug, as I've done for you.

Comment: FYI, I don't believe "default" is a valid value for width and height attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float clearing has been well covered many times over. You might give that a search. In this case I'd probably encapsulate the image and the paragraphs which you *do* want to float in a div having hidden overflow. This forces it to contain its content. Since divs and paragraphs are both block-level, they'll stack.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}

p.username {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* for demonstration only */
p {
  background: pink;
}

div {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="My portrait">
  <p class="username">@BilalKhan615</p>
  <p>Getting started with HTML and CSS!</p>
</div>

<p> Hello Everyone!</p>
```